Orthogonality in Hilbert algebras and congruence
Consider a finite-dimensional Hilbert space $V$ (say, over $\mathbb{C}$) and a finite-dimensional Hilbert algebra $A$ (i.e., Hilbert space with a compatible associative unitary algebra structure). Consider the tensor product $W = A \otimes V$, which is naturally a Hilbert space and a module over $A$.
Suppose that for $x,y \in W$, the following holds: for every $z \in V$, $1 \otimes z$ is orthogonal to $x$ if and only if it is orthogonal to $y$. Here, $1$ denotes the unit of $A$. In other words, we have
$$
x^\perp \cap (1 \otimes V) = y^\perp \cap (1 \otimes V). 
$$
Is it true that $x$ and $y$ are congruent modulo $A$ i.e., there exist $a \in A$ such that $a \  x = y$?
Thank you in advance for your help.

No way. Take $A = V = \mathbb{C}^2$, giving $A$ the coordinatewise product. Let $e_1$ and $e_2$ be the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{C}^2$ and take $x = (e_1 - e_2)\otimes e_1$ and $y = (e_1 - e_2)\otimes e_2$ in $A \otimes V$. These are both orthogonal to everything of the form $1\otimes z$ since $1 = e_1 + e_2$, but neither is a multiple of the other.
